# Action Script 3 (1136:Incorrect Number of arguments)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I am starting with as3, but i find some error in program popping up.

My as3 program:

```
var a:Array=new Array();

var i:int;
for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
    var k:Hello = new Hello(i);
    a.push(k);
}
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    a[i].x=i*100;
    trace(a[i].age);
    addChild(a[i]);
}
```

and my as program :

```
package{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.stage;

    public class Hello extends MovieClip{
        public var age:int;


        public function Hello(i:int){
            this.age=m;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide some more information for people to be able to help you. For example: The error that pops up as well as where in your code it happens.

Comment: Your mentioned code can not give that error, but you have to change `import flash.display.stage;` to `import flash.display.Stage;` and `this.age = m;` to `this.age = i;`. Try again, and if the error is fired, put all your code.

Answer (score 0):

You assigned `m` variable to `age`. What is `m`? You should write `this.age=i;`.

```
public function Hello(i:int){
    this.age=m;
}
```

And remove `import flash.display.stage;`.

Comment: i did change but still facing the same problem :(